# TableLayoutPanel doesn't change the last row index after deleting a row

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I have added 4 control as `myControli`-i is the row index- into a `TableLayoutPanel`. Then I deleted the 3rd row programmatically. But when I call `TableLayoutPanel.GetRow(myControl3)`, it returns 3 as row number instead of 2. Why it doesn't rearrange the row indexes after deleting a row?

[image]

```
private void deleteButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(button3);
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount -= 1;
        Debug.WriteLine(tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(button4));
        //Returns 3
    }
```

**UPDATE:** I have updated the code sample to be more clear and uploaded an image.
The table layout has 4 `AutoSize` rows, 1 column. The buttons was added in design time.

Comment: You should post your actual code (this one wouldn't compile), to determine how the Controls are added to the `TableLayoutPanel` and specify what is the `TLP` Layout (the Rows are set to AutoSize, for example). To get the `(Column, Row)` of a Control, use the [TableLayoutPanel.GetPositionFromControl(Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getpositionfromcontrol) Method

Comment: I would use a FlowLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: Without testing I would say it's the expected index. You removed a button, not a row, sow the button 4 is always in the fourth row (index 3)

Comment: @Manta  `RowCount -= 1` removes a row. But `.GetRow([Control])` it's function provided by the Row object. There's a conflict of attibutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you cannot remove a row "in the middle". `RowCount` remove the last row. What you have to do is :

-remove the control

-move up all the controls after the row you want to delete

-delete row

In your case :

```
    private void deleteButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(button3);
        tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(button4, 2);
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount -= 1;
        Debug.WriteLine(tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(button4));
    }
```

And you can write a simple method to do that...

Comment: With a little additional code this worked for me. Thanks!